# Yii2 signup form in another view as well as the default signup view

Tags: php, yii2

I am using yii2 and I wish to add the signup form to a view within site/report/create.php

I currently have it so if the user isn't logged in it displays a message and if they are displays the create report form.

How can I use the user model within my report view that will also need to use the report model. Is it a matter of adapting the below code to specify the user model? If so how would that be done.

```
<?= $this->render('_form', [
    'model' => $model,
]) ?>
```

Comment: In your create view, you just want to check if user is logged in or not?

Comment: @Tahir No I want to be able to render the sign up form in a view which currently does have access to the sign up/user model.

Answer (score 0):

Since signup form itself is in a view, you can render a view in another view using `render` method.

First, from controller action you need to pass signup model to view like this:

```
return $this->render('create', [
    'model' => $model,
    'signupModel' => $signupModel,
]);
```

Then inside create view, you need to pass this signup model to signup view

```
<?= $this->render('signup.php', ['model' => $signupModel]); ?>
```

To read more about rendering view inside another view look at docs [Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#rendering-in-views) and [Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html#render()-detail)

Comment: Thank looks like an answer I understand I will try implement it when I get home from work.